# Issue with hash table chaining in C

Tags: c

My homework an introductory C class is to complete the implementation of a hash table with dynamic allocation. I have to use the header file provided and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Header file:

```
/// structure for the nodes of the chains
struct node_s {
    char *key;
    int value;
    struct node_s *link;
};

/// This is the main structure for the overall table.
struct table_s {
    /// This should be used as a pointer to a dynamically
    /// allocated array of pointers to node structures.
    struct node_s **table;

    /// This is for storing the maximum number of buckets/lists in the table.
    size_t bins;

    /// This is for storing the current number of elements in the table
    size_t size;
};
    /// A convenience declaration for referring to a pointer to a HT..
    typedef struct table_s *hash_t;
```

What I need to implement:

```
/// Allocate a table with some initial empty bins.
/// @param bins -- the number of bins in the table (initally empty)
/// @return -- a pointer to a dynamically allocated hash table
hash_t create_table(int bins){
        struct node_s *nodes[bins];
        for(int i = 0; i < bins; i++){
                nodes[i] = NULL;
        }
        hash_t table = malloc(sizeof(hash_t));
        table -> table = nodes;
        table -> bins = bins;
        table -> size = 0;
        return table;
}

/// Set the value for a key in a given hash table.
/// @note -- if this is the first time setting this key, then the
///          table must make a dynamic copy of the string.  This
///          copy must be freed when the table is freed.
/// @note -- if the table exceeds a load factor of 1 after setting
///          the key/value pair, then this function should trigger
///          rehashing into a larger table.  It will then deallocate
///          the table field in the table_s structure, but it will
///          NOT free the table address in the table parameter.
/// @param table -- a pointer to a hash table

void set(hash_t table, char *key, int value){
        int index = hash(key) % table -> bins;
        printf("Index: %d\n", index);
        struct node_s *node = table -> table[index];
        struct node_s *newNode = malloc(sizeof(newNode));
        newNode -> key  = key;
        newNode -> value = value;
        newNode -> link = NULL;

        printf("New node, key: %s\n", newNode -> key);
        if(node == NULL){
                printf("Filled bucket!\n");
                table -> table[index] = newNode;
                table -> size = table -> size + 1;
        }else{
                printf("Chained!\n");
                while(node -> link != NULL){
                        node = node -> link;
                }
                node -> link  = newNode;
        }
        printf("\n");
}
```

What runs:

```
 char key[max_key];
    hash_t table = create_table(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < trials; i++) {
        int sample = rand() % max_num;
        sprintf(key, "%d", sample);
        set(table, key, sample);
    }
```

Output:

```
Index: 7
New node, index: 7, key: 83
NULL!
New bucket filled!

Index: 0
New node, index: 0, key: 86
NOT NULL!
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Expected output:

```
Index: 7
New node, index: 7, key: 83
NULL!
New bucket filled!

Index: 0
New node, index: 0, key: 86
NULL!
New bucket filled!
```

And so on, until a collision when the node at index is not NULL, where newNode chains itself by replacing the NULL *link of the last node present.

I know my chaining isn't quite correct yet and needs to be expanded upon, but I'm just really confused as to why it's not registering the NULL at index and placing a new linked list node, and is instead trying to add onto the linked list as though there was a collision.

Comment: You are not chaining. `node -> link = newNode;` will always set `->link` to the `newNode` overwriting anything that is there creating a memory leak. Instead you need `newNode->link = node; node = newNode;` Which sets `table->table[index];` to the `newNode` and existing nodes are chained. Otherwise you must iterate to the end of the chain.  You may find [Coding up a Hash Table](http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/searching/hashtables/section3.rhtml) and [Hash tables - eternally confuzzled](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx) useful.

Comment: Also point your instructor to [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers). Which also leads to confusion.

Comment: In `create_table`, `nodes` is on the _stack_, so it goes out of scope when the function returns. Thus, you can't [legitmately] return this in `table->table`, as upon return, dereferencing `table->table` is undefined behavior. Replace [all] this with: `table->table = calloc(bins,sizeof(struct node_s *));`

Comment: The malloc calls do not allocate the correct amount of memory. As pointed out, your instructor is wrong in suggesting "convenience" pointer typedefs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coding tip: Don't put a space before/after the dot `.` or arrow `->` operators.

Instead of this:

```
table -> bins
```

This:

```
table->bins
```

Your actual issue is this.  `create_table` isn't propertly allocating memory for bins.  Even worse, it's using an array on the stack.  That memory is undefined behavior as soon as create_table returns.  Better:

```
hash_t create_table(int bins){
        hash_t table = malloc(sizeof(hash_t));
        table->table = calloc(sizeof(struct node_s*) * bins); //malloc and zero-init
        table->bins = bins
        table->size = 0;
        return table;
}
```

Also, instead of this:

```
        if(node == NULL){
                printf("Filled bucket!\n");
                table -> table[index] = newNode;
                table -> size = table -> size + 1;
        }else{
                printf("Chained!\n");
                while(node -> link != NULL){
                        node = node -> link;
                }
                node -> link  = newNode;
        }
```

Just do this:

```
printf("%s\n", (table->table[index] ? "Filled bucked!" : "Chained!"));
newNode->link = table->table[index];
table->table[index] = newNode;
```

Each time a new node gets added to a bin, it becomes the head item in the bin's linked list.  The chaining happens at the front of the each bin's list instead of the back.